# What do I gain if a number is Quadratic residues?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

If in a random question, I see:

$1)\:\: x^2 = a\pmod p$, $p$ is a prime.
$2)\:\: a$ is quadratic residues $(QR)$.

How can I conclude that $(a, p)=1$ ? What is missing to determine that? I learned in class the opposite direction: If $p$ is prime, $(a, p)=1$ and $a$ is perfect square modolo $p$, then $a$ is $QR$.

**In other words, what do I gain if a number is Quadratic residues?**

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused, if p is a prime then (a,p) = 1?

Comment: maby p devides a and maby not. thats what im asking

Comment: The requirement that $(a,p)=1$ is built into the usual definition of quadratic residue of $p$. True, if $p\mid a$, then $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has a solution. But it is inconvenient to call $0$ a quadratic residue of $p$. A lot of the nice results, such as the fact that there are equal numbers of quadratic residues and non-residues, would have to be reworded.

Comment: @AndréNicolas i did not understood what is your answer to what i asked.

Comment: I was answering the question "how can I conclude that $(a,p)=1$?".   As to what do we gain, sometimes knowing that $a$ is a non-residue helps us show that a Diophantine equation has no solution. There are many other uses in number theory. I did not want to give a formal answer to that question, since a good answer would require a fairly long list, with detail.

Comment: okay thanks. last question, how can I call a if p | a and x^2=a(mod p) has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"a is a quadratic residue mod $p$" *means* $\exists x$ such that $x^2=a$ mod $p$ and $(a,p)=1$. That's the definition.

If $p|a$ and $x^2=a$ then you call $a$ a multiple of $p$. Every multiple of $p$ has such an $x$, because $x=0$ satisfies that equation, so in that case you're not actually pointing anything out by calling it a QR.